# How do I use a variable inside of a shorthand if/else statement in a PHP for() loop?

Tags: php, css, variables, for-loop, syntax

I am trying to use a FOR loop to write dynamic CSS. The CSS needs to change based on how many items are in a database table. Here is my attempt, but it is not giving me the output I desire:

```
    <?php
    $count_posts = wp_count_posts( 'portfolio' )->publish; // This is for a wordpress site.
    $slidecount = ceil( $count_posts / 3 ); // there are 3 database entries in each "slide".

    for ($c = 0 ; $c < $slidecount; $c++){ 
    echo '#slide' . ($c + 1) . ':checked ~ #controls label.c-label' . ($c < $slidecount ? (($c + 2) . ', ') : '1'); // This is the part I'm not sure on... How do I properly nest the ($c + 2) expression into a shorthand if/else statement ??
    }
    echo ' {' . "\n" . 'float: right;' . "\n" . 'display: block; }' . "\n";
    ?>
```

Output (when there are 5 items in the database table):

```
            #slide1:checked ~ #controls label.c-label2, 
    #slide2:checked ~ #controls label.c-label3, 
    #slide3:checked ~ #controls label.c-label4, 
    #slide4:checked ~ #controls label.c-label5, 
    #slide5:checked ~ #controls label.c-label6 {
    float: right;
    display: block;
    }
```

Desired output:

```
    #slide1:checked ~ #controls label.c-label2, 
    #slide2:checked ~ #controls label.c-label3, 
    #slide3:checked ~ #controls label.c-label4, 
    #slide4:checked ~ #controls label.c-label5, 
    #slide5:checked ~ #controls label.c-label1 {
    float: right;
    display: block;
    }
```

I want the last execution of the FOR loop to append a '1' to the end of 'label', so that the CSS selector points back to the first  element "c-label1". This is being used to build a pure CSS slider that changes the slides using radio buttons and needs to loop the slides back to the beginning once it gets to the end. I need the code to automatically update whenever there is a new database entry saved.

Can anyone help me clean up the code so it works?

Thank you SO much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you are using `$c < $slidecount` in your statement but your `$c` value starts from 0 so it will never happen to match your `slidecount` and won't be false.
You should also change your round bracket `()`

A quick solution could be to add 1 to your `$c` variable. This should work

```
(($c+1) < $slidecount ? ($c + 2) . ', ' : '1');
```

Comment: Your answer is excellent. Thank you. I already checked @Segabond's answer as correct, because he was first.

Comment: @user2655393 You are welcome, but i guess it shouldn't be a time thing but a more exhaustive answer.

Comment: You're right. I'm marking this as the answer, because it is the most exhaustive, where as the others only have parts that are correct.

Answer (score 2):

In your for loop condition you have

```
$c < $slidecount
```

It means that the same condition in your loop body is also met, so your code to generate c-label1 will never be executed.

Try changing

```
$c < $slidecount
```

to

```
($c < ($slidecount-1))
```

Comment: Fabio's answer is more exhaustive. I've marked his as the best answer.

Comment: I dont see how it is more exhaustive and in addition to this, his first answer was completely off. Anyway thanks a lot for taking my 15 reputation points. Good work :)

Comment: It's more exhaustive because it includes both problems with my original code: (1) the fact that my `$c` variable will never be equal to the `$slidecount` variable (which is what you also said), and (2) the correct syntax for concatenating the `($c + 2) . ', '` expression. Hence a more exhaustive answer, barely. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

It is how you are using `(` and `)`. try this:

```
echo '#slide' . ($c + 1) . ':checked ~ #controls label.c-label' . ($c < $slidecount ? $c + 2 . ', ': '1');
```